# How to change Fancyref's page numbering behaviour?

Tags: cross-referencing, page-numbering, fancyref

I am using the Fancyref (\Fref{}) package for cross referencing but every reference is in the form "*Figure 4 on the next page*". How can I tell the package to only include "*on page xxx*" if the reference target is far away (e.g more than 5 pages)?

Comment: +1 for an interesting suggested feature.  But, don't you think the reader will be confused when only some figures direct the reader to the page?

Comment: The majority of references are close to the figure so this shouldn't be a problem. I'm only really after the page numbers for a few references to far away figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `fancyref` uses package `varioref`. `\reftextafter`, `\reftextbefore` can be redefined to suppress their texts. Also `\reftextfaraway` can be redefined that it only prints the text, if the referenced object is five or more pages away:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyref}

\renewcommand*{\reftextfaceafter}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextafter}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextfacebefore}{\unskip}
\renewcommand*{\reftextbefore}{\unskip}
\makeatletter
\let\saved@reftextfaraway\reftextfaraway
\renewcommand*{\reftextfaraway}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\ref@unknown@value{??}%
    \ifx\@tempa\ref@unknown@value
      \count@=0 %
    \else
      \count@\thevpagerefnum\relax
      \advance\count@ by -\@tempa\relax
      \ifnum\count@<0 \count@=-\count@\fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\count@<5 %
      \unskip
    \else
      \saved@reftextfaraway{#1}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Dummy figure}
  \label{fig:dummy}
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\clearpage
\Fref{fig:dummy} contains a dummy figure.
\end{document}
```

Result:

> ```
> <Page 1> Figure 1: Dummy figure
> <Page 2> Figure 1 contains a dummy figure.
> <Page 3> Figure 1 contains a dummy figure.
> <Page 4> Figure 1 contains a dummy figure.
> <Page 5> Figure 1 contains a dummy figure.
> <Page 6> Figure 1 on page 1 contains a dummy figure.
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much for this code.
I had to put includes for babel and amsmath after fancyref, after doing this it worked perfectly.

Comment: This answer was very useful! I extended it into a sty file for an easier usage, and replaced the 5 by a `threshold` parameter to the package: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651670/refwithpage-latex-script-to-add-page-number-only-if-farther-than-a-threshold/651809#651809